# Rails 5 has_many through: association creates 2 records for intermediary model

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I'm trying to setup a Rails 5 has_many through: type of association on three models. The goal is to have one form the user can fill out that edits or creates all three models (and associations).

Project is the "intermediary" model.

Here are my models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :projects
    has_many :programmers, through: :projects

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :programmers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true
  belongs_to :programmer, optional: true 
end

class Programmer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :clients, through: :projects
end
```

Postgres Schema:

```
create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "programmers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "client_id"
  t.integer  "programmer_id"
  t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_projects_on_client_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["programmer_id"], name: "index_projects_on_programmer_id", using: :btree
end

add_foreign_key "projects", "clients"
add_foreign_key "projects", "programmers"
```

Clients Controller (just the new/create & param parts)

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
  @client.projects.build
  @client.programmers.build
end

def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.save
      format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:id, :name, projects_attributes: [:id, :name], programmers_attributes: [:id, :name])
 end
```

And finally, the form:

```
<%= form_for(client) do |f| %>
 <% if client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <label>Client name</label>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <br />

  <%= f.fields_for :projects do |projectfields| %>
    <label>Project name</label>
    <%= projectfields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <br />

  <%= f.fields_for :programmers do |programmerfields| %>
    <label>Programmer name</label>
    <%= programmerfields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Console log:

```
Started POST "/clients" for ::1 at 2016-11-09 09:14:31 -0800
Processing by ClientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"6QouF/zC+ivHAlbEvnhuBob80/AGt2QFmn0xa569+wJ8iWRmDOnz229OJq6PxaYRnzjNoDf8j71Jf2FpY3FMZw==", "client"=>{"name"=>"aaa", "projects_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"bbb"}}, "programmers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"ccc"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Client"}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["name", "aaa"]]
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name", "client_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["name", "bbb"], ["client_id", 1]]
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "programmers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["name", "ccc"]]
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("created_at", "updated_at", "client_id", "programmer_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-09 17:14:31 UTC], ["client_id", 1], ["programmer_id", 1]]
(5.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/clients/1
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
```

So it's basically working to create entries for all three models, **EXCEPT that there are 2 DB entries created for Projects** that look like this:

[image]

I've been staring at this too long and figure I must be missing something obvious. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot and see if it works:

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>

<% if client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <label>Client name</label>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <br />

  <%= f.fields_for @client.projects do |projectfields| %>
    <label>Project name</label>
    <%= projectfields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <br />

  <%= f.fields_for @client.programmers do |programmerfields| %>
    <label>Programmer name</label>
    <%= programmerfields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think this is closer -- after a bunch of fussing it looks like the key might be to nest the field_for programmers inside the fields_for projects block?